# Events are not showing from selected site in SharePoint Online Modern Event webpart

Tags: modern-experience, sharepoint-calendar

I have one site where I am creating events in **Events** list. I have to show events from this list to other site.
One other site, I used Modern Event webpart but that webpart don't show events. As per my knowledge, webpart configurations are correct. Initially I thought this was happened due to search so I reindexed source Event list and site but still i don't see the events.

BTW, I have M365 Global Admin access and configured Events webpart using that access.

[image]

[image]

Comment: same issue with me. I wait 1 week maybe columns are not yet index but same results.